# javascript check document for element to apply a value

Tags: javascript, function, resize

i'm pretty new to javascript and have been stuck on this all day. I have a script which resize element according to screen res it all works except I need to have "if element DOES NOT exist on document then add an addittional value "242px" into contentContainer.css method" this is what I have so far so that this eleemnt takes up the space of the asideContent element when its not on the page...

```
            <script>

             // DOM Container Resize Handler

                 var extra = ($("body.asideContent").length == 0) ? 242 : 0;

                 var adjustStyle = function() {
                 var winWidth = $(window).width(),
                  width = parseInt(winWidth),
                  container = $('body .fixed');
               contentContainer = $('body .content');
                   if (width >= 1454) {
                        container.css('width','1454px');
                        contentContainer.css('width',extra + 1210 + "px");
                    } else if ((width < 1454) & (width >= 1212)) { 
                        container.css('width','1212px');
                        contentContainer.css('width',extra + 968 + "px");
                    } else {
                       container.css('width','970px');
                       contentContainer.css('width',extra + 726 + "px");
                    }
                };
                 $(function() {
                    var filterWrap = $("#filterWrap"),
                        offset = filterWrap.offset(),
                        topPadding = 15;

                    $(window).scroll(function() {
                        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                            filterWrap.stop().animate({
                                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                            });
                        } else {
                            filterWrap.stop().animate({
                                marginTop: 0
                            });
                        };
                    });

                    // DOM Container Resize Handler - Initialization    
                    $(window).resize(function() {
                        adjustStyle();
                    });
                    adjustStyle();
                });
            </script>
```

Its applying the extra all the time, add I only want to apply this when ("body.asideContent") is not in the document

test html

```
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="fixed">
                    <div id="container">
                        <div class="asideContent">&nbsp</div>
                        <div class="content">&nbsp</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Just want to say thank you in advance for any help you can give me... its been driving me crazy all day...

Answer (score 1):

`body.asideContent` means a body with a class of asideContent. Try

```
$("body .asideContent")
```

(aka, with a space between body and .asideContent)

Comment: its still adding 242 when .asideContent is in the page :(